# The shortest distance between a point and a figure

Tags: calculus

I noted subjects speaking about point and surface but my question is more global.
Let a set of figures (polygons, cercles,...) in a plan, does exist a formula for computing the shortest distance between a point and the figures ?
The idea is to apply that to an object (the point) moving in the plan, with a V speed, and to know by advance WHEN the object could be IN a figure.

Answer (score 2):

For a polygon, a naive solution is to find the distance $d_i$ from the point $X$ to each vertex $P_i$ of the polygon and take the minimum value of the $d_i$s. Then take the distance from the point $X$ to the line segments between $P_{i-1}P_i$ and $P_iP_{i+1}$.

A circle is much easier: take the distance between the point $(x, y)$ and the center of the circle $(h, k)$. Now subtract the radius $r$.

With that in mind, an approximate solution for any figure is to find a circle which circumscribes the figure. This allows you to quickly determine a lower bound for the distance between a point and the figure.

Comment: Yes it is a naive solution for "two simple figures". Could a global solution consider the figures as lines ? And the algorythm could be long if the nombre of figures is great.

Comment: @user62025 Finding the distance between a point and a "figure" will be $O(n)$ in the number of figures at best. I'm not sure what you mean by "consider the figures as lines". Can you elaborate (maybe in an edit to your question)?

Comment: I have a problem of translation ... I could say the border of the figure (ie, for a circle, the circumnference is a line). But is it possible to put in equation a line ?

Comment: @user In mathematics, a "line" is straight and continues forever in both directions. Other one dimensional figures (eg parabolas, cubics, etc.) are called "curves". For distance calculations, a circle is the simplest as stated in the second paragraph of my answer. Trying to convert a circle into a line seems to unnecessarily complicate the issue.